# MultiSelectListPreference not showing values

Tags: android, preferences, android-multiselectlistpreference

I have created a MultiSelectListPreference. It does not show ANY multi-selection list, of the default_aliases. It only shows the text "Choose aliases" (dialogMessage) in the opened dialog.

```
    <MultiSelectListPreference
        android:title="@string/aliases"
        android:positiveButtonText="@android:string/ok" 
        android:negativeButtonText="@android:string/cancel" 
        android:dialogTitle="Aliases" 
        android:key="aliases" 
        android:dialogMessage="Choose aliases" 
        android:defaultValue="@array/default_aliases" 
        android:entryValues="@array/default_aliases" 
        android:entries="@array/default_aliases"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

MultiSelectListPreference, being a DialogPreference, has the inherited "dialogMessage" attribute. You would think this message should be an explanation (for the user) on the selection - but NO. The dialog widget simply shows JUST the message, and totally ignores the multi-selection part.

**The solution** is not to supply a "dialogMessage" at all.

This is a weird behavior, and looks a bit like an Android bug. I am using api 15 (4.1).